# Date parsing and timezone adjusting in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I have about 800,000 rows of data in a dataframe, and one column of the data df['Date'] is string of time and date **'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fff'**, which doesn't have timezone information. However I know they are in New_York timezone and they need to be convert into CET. Now I have two methods to get the job done:

method 1 (very slow for sure):

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: timezone('America/New_York')\
            .localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S.%f'))\
            .astimezone(timezone('CET')))
```

method 2 :

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S.%f')
df.index.tz_localize('America/New_York').tz_convert('CET')
```

I am just wondering if there are any other better ways to do it? or any potential pitfalls of the methods I listed? Thanks!

Also, I would like to shift all timestamp by a fix amount of time, such as 1ms **`timedelta(0,0,1000)`**, how can I implement it using method 2?

Comment: I'd expect the second method to be significantly faster, the first is going to perform the conversion row-wise and this would be how I'd do this

Comment: In any case, the second one is the "pandas" way of doing this (using the built-in functions), so no need to look for other ways I think

Comment: If I want to shift all timestamp by a centain time such 1ms (timedelta(0,0,1000)), how can I do it?

Comment: You can just construct a timedelta and add it to offset it e.g `df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='ms')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 2 is definately the best way of doing this.

However, it occurs to me that you are formatting this date after you have loaded the data.

It is much faster to parse dates on load of a file, than it is to change them after you have loaded it. (Not to mention cleaner)

If your data is loaded from a csv file using the [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) function for instance, then you can use the `parse_dates=` option and the `date_parser=` option.

You can try it out directly with your lambda function as the `date_parser=`
and just set the `parse_dates=` to a list of your date columns.

Like this:

```
pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', parse_dates=['Date'] date_parser=lambda x: timezone('America/New_York')\
        .localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S.%f'))\
        .astimezone(timezone('CET')))
```

Should work and will probably be the fastest.